# how to prevent game restart when change orientation in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

i am developing a game in which i have to use both landscape mode for my game scene.
but when i change `orientation` my game restart and load from splash screen how to stop this.

could any one please help me.

i am using

```
final EngineOptions eo = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_SENSOR,
     new FillResolutionPolicy(), _camera);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html. Please check the documentation under the heading *Handling the Configuration Change Yourself*.

```
<activity android:name=".Activity_name"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
```

Screen size to be added for 3.2 and above.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
       //do something
    }
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
       //do something        
    }
}
```

I assume you have a splash screen and after displaying splash screen navigates to activity called Main. In this case your splash screen should run only once when the app is started. You have to call finish() before navigating to next activity. Splash Screen gets destroyed and you navigate to next screen.

Comment: i am using landscape mode only in both directions. and when i change to second landscape mode my game restarts.

Comment: When orientation changes your activity will be destroyed and created again.

Comment: the documentation link should provide you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

add following in your manifest file in your activity tag

```
android:ConfigChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screensize"
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i already added this in my manifest file

Answer (score 0):

add screenOrientation tag in your GameActivity in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity
        android:name=".YourgameActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
 </activity>
```